# S3 SNS Notification with Custom SNS MessageAttributes

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-sns

Is it possible to add CustomAttributes to an SNS publication that is initiated from an S3 Object Created Event notification?  I'm am trying to promote content to context to facilitate message filtering?

Comment: The direct answer to the question is "no," but perhaps if you explain what you are specifically hoping to accomplish ("promote content to context?" I'm not quite clear on what that means) then perhaps there's an alternative.  Hypothetically, if it were possible, how would you set it? What would it contain?

Comment: I am trying to accomplish subscription filtering that's all.  S3 will broadcast to a Topic and subscribed to by N services.  Only 1 of N will process that particular sub bucket document.  Having message attributes allows for quick key search for filtering and existing code rather than deserializing message content to search for known S3 property value (i.e. key)

Comment: It seems like you might want to let a Lambda function analyze each message and then only deliver it to the appropriate places -- otherwise you're paying for delivery of messsages that will, statistically speaking, be discarded more often than not.  Granted, you'll have to deserialize it, but the net CPU cycles spent doing this would be lower.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot I agree, I generally try to avoid the Lambda brokering pattern since it breaks pub/sub decoupling but you may be correct in regards to wasted cycles since this is pay-per-use not depreciating cost